# How we can filter only user added attacments from someone's signature logo in email

Tags: email

Hi have developed one salesforce app where i am storing all emails sent by app users using InboundEmail. Every user also attaching some file and sending to salesforce but my problem is if user attached any single file and sent to salesforce i am getting attachment plus that user email signature logo. I want to filer all signature logo and i have to store only user added attacments. How i can achieve this in to salesforce.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details on your problem, screenshots, sample code please. I'm not familiar with what your talking about and a picture and/or sample code might help. Thanks!

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000g5DMAAY this link will give u some idea about what i am saying.

Comment: I understand a bit better now, thanks. When you say InBoundEmail, are you refering to this feature, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound.htm, if so can you provide the code?